# How to Properly Update the Status of a Job

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-jobs

As far as I know, when most people want to know if a `Kubernetes` (or `Spark` even) `Job` is done, they initiate some sort of loop somewhere to periodically check if the `Job` is finished with the respective `API`.

Right now, I'm doing that with `Kubernetes` in the background with the `disown` (`&`) operator (`bash` inside `Python` below):

```py
import subprocess

cmd = f'''
kubectl wait \\
    --for=condition=complete \\
    --timeout=-1s \\
    job/job_name \\
    > logs/kube_wait_log.txt \\
    &
'''

kube_listen = subprocess.run(
    cmd,
    shell = True,
    stdout = subprocess.PIPE
)
```

So... I actually have *two* (correlated) questions:

1. Is there a better way of doing this in the background with `shell` other than with the `&` operator?
2. The option that I think would be best is actually to use `cURL` from inside the `Job` to update my `Local Server API` that interacts with `Kubernetes`.

   - However, I don't know how I can perform a `cURL` from a `Job`. Is it possible?
   - I imagine you would have to expose ports somewhere but where? And is it really supported? Could you create a `Kubernetes` `Service` to manage the ports and connections?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to block on a process running to completion, you can create a [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) instance instead.  Once you have this, you can [`poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) it to see if it's completed.  (You should try really really really hard to avoid using `shell=True` if at all possible.)  So one variation of this could look like (untested):

```py
with open('logs/kube_wait_log.txt', 'w') as f:
  with subprocess.Popen(['kubectl', 'wait',
                         '--for=condition=complete',
                         '--timeout=-1s',
                         'job/job_name'],
                         stdin=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                         stdout=f,
                         stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as p:
    while True:
      if p.poll():
        job_is_complete()
        break
      time.sleep(1)
```

Better than shelling out to `kubectl`, though, is using the [official Kubernetes Python client library](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/).  Rather than using this "wait" operation, you would [watch](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-concepts/#efficient-detection-of-changes) the job object in question and see if its status changes to "completed".  This could look roughly like (untested):

```py
from kubernetes import client, watch
jobsv1 = client.BatchV1Api()
w = watch.watch()
for event in w.stream(jobsv1.read_namespaced_job, 'job_name', 'default'):
  job = event['object']
  if job.status.completion_time is not None:
    job_is_complete()
    break
```

The Job's Pod doesn't need to update its own status with the Kubernetes server.  It just needs to exit with a successful status code (0) when it's done, and that will get reflected in the Job's status field.

Comment: Really nice answer. Thank you. Would you confirm that listening until the `Job` is complete is the best practice? Really nice `Python` option you mentioned, but I might still have to use shelling anyway because I think it would make the code more manageable by other people because not everyone here uses `Python`. By the way, do you have `Kubernetes` *resources* you would recommend to newcomers?

Comment: Kubernetes’ native API is in Go, if that’s better.  I’d start by going to https://kubernetes.io/ and clicking the “Documentation” link at the top; do as much as you can by writing out YAML files and using `kubectl apply`, try to avoid imperative commands like `kubectl create`.  Transitioning from there to using the API is fairly straightforward.